# I am trying to make a simple clicker game, but the global variable will not work

Tags: javascript, global-variables

The problem is that when I run the code and press the "Show money" button, it just logs the variable as "undefined". It seems to be a problem with the global variable because I am using JSFiddle and in the functions, the variable "money" does not get colored blue.

Here is the html:

```
<b>
Click the spacebar to get money
</b>
<button onclick="showMoney()">
Show money
</button>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var money = 0;
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    money + 1;
  }
}

function showMoney() {
  console.log(money)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, money is defined, but always equal to 0.

I changed it so money will increment when your key is released, everything works fine...

```
var money = 0;

document.addEventListener('keyup', addMoney);

function addMoney(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    money++;
    }
}

function showMoney() {
  console.log(money)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L7xhs48o/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! I started programming in like 5th grade with the inspect menu on a computer, and I thought of how fun it really was to mess around with it. I started learning more javascript, html, and css online. I am now in 7th grade, and there is still not any programming classes I can take. I realized that programming is like a world of your own, and you can do anything you want. I always like to learn more about it!

Comment: That's a great spirit to have here ! I'm glad I could help you, keep going, programmation is awesome :)

Comment: Usually I am only interested in one topic for like, not even a couple of days, but when I started programming, I have never stopped since(sometimes I get into programming to figure out what different things do for so long of a time that when I try to write things in regular english I tend to program more instead)